# Can someone help me identify the is connector?

Tags: identification, connector, wire

I'm repairing an old coffee machine and one of the wires came out the its connector. I'd like to order the connector and the proper crimps to repair it but I'm unsure of which type/size to order.

Here are some pictures:

[image: connector dimensions]

Comment: Pin pitch is ... ?

Comment: Search JST's website.

Comment: https://www.jst.com

Answer (score 2):

pin pitch looks to be about 2mm and the style looks like JST, so

JST PH series.

Comment: Yep this is correct. I use these exact ones all the time.